# Individual pst files for individual outlook 2010 folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I was wondering if it is possible for the following scenario:

Suppose I have 5 folders in my Microsoft Outlook 2010.
Currently, there are 1 pst file that contain the 5 folders. Each folders contain emails that are grouped according to the folder name.

So, can I have 5 pst file, whereby 1 pst file for 1 folder?

This is because at some other time, I will create new folder(s) and existing folder I may remove from Outlook (but still able to make a copy of the pst file)

Comment: No, it’s not possible.

Comment: @kinokijuf, I dun mind using other application that can create individual file for each of my individual mail folder as long as the application can connect to my Outlook Exchange. I need a application (or other workarounds) that can manage my email in a orderly manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PST files as sub-folders but you can create the separate PST files and basically use them as high level folders in Outlook.

You can then create Rules to move messages into different PST files based on different criteria (e.g. certain words, subject, email addresses). Outlook also supports dragging messages/folders from one PST to another so it should do most of what you need.